# Cant get <ul><li> horizontal

Tags: html, css

This list was working fine a week ago, but today I opened up my website and it just decided not to be horizontal anymore.

[image]

```
.you ul, .dealer ul {    
      list-style-type: none; 
      overflow: hidden; 
      padding: 0; 
      margin: 0;
}    
.you li, .dealer li { 
      margin: 0; 
      padding: 0; 
      float: left;
} 

   <h3>You:</h3>
   <div class="you">
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="y in you">
         <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{y.imageUrl}}">
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <h3>Dealer:</h3>
   <div class="dealer">
     <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="d in dealer">
         <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{d.imageUrl}}">
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: "This list was working fine a week ago, but today I opened up my website and it just decided not to be horizontal anymore." That's really not how websites work. Show us a working example of your problem, not a screenshot.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like the `li` are too big for the `ul` so are wrapping onto the next line. The fact that `ul` has `overflow: hidden;` which isn't taking effect would suggest that there are external forces at play outside of what you have posted. Please provide us with all the code required to replicate the issue.

Comment: Se to your UL a width and check the li elements are not bigger than the ul width including paddings and margins. Otherwise give us a fiddle or more code.

Comment: Can u put ur html as well in the post?